# Warning Citation undefined even after defining citation in the .bib file

Tags: biblatex, warnings, winedt

I have defined all the citations for my report in the separate `.bib` file. And I am using package `biblatex` for my bibliography. But wherever I cite my articles and compile using `PDFTeXify`, I get warnings that my citations are not defined and Bibliography page is not created because of that.

for eg:

I have cited an article from my `.bib` file in a separate `.tex` file, you can see the warnings in the console window.

[image]

My `.bib` file is as follows:

[image]

And My main `project_report.tex` file where I have imported `biblatex` package and `.bib` file is as follows

[image]

Comment: There is a syntax error in your bib file. There needs to be a comma after `author = {Google}`. Also double check you are running `biber`.

Comment: There's a second syntax error in the `mumbaimirror` entry: it's currently lacking a comma at the end of the `title` field.

Comment: These missing commas described above will break the compilation and prevent all entries after the syntax error from processing. Also, are you sure that your bib file is named bibliography.bib instead of bibliography.bib?